# optimal taxonomy or custom post types

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, database

hi everyone on this community,

i've been researching this but everytime i think i'm getting somewhere, i hit a dead end and have to start again; so i thought i'd reach out to this community for some help.

I have an ecommerce site which i'm looking to create for a customer, based on WP+Woocommerce and Dokan (Multi Vendor Solution Provider).

The challenge i have is that this is a parts company, which sells parts for vehicles.

The "Parts" will be products, which themselves fit under multiple layers of categories. The part will have a condition (new, used, refurished etc) which can be done by custom fields (ACF). Great.

What I want next is to be able to list out the compatible vehicles for Part "X", and model numbers of those vehicles in a list/data table within the product.

So "X" Part, is compatible with:

Vehicle Types: Cars, Buses, Vans

Makers: BMW

Models: X1, X5, X6, X9 etc.

I can do this with tags, but i think this will quickly get out of control; and because this is structured data i think it'll be taxonomies?
i also need to be able to pre-populate a bunch of vehicles into the taxonomies list, and have the other values prepopulated.
So if i select X1, then it will know X1 is a car, and maker BMW and populate this value.

not really sure how to achieve this? or what your recommendations would be.

do let me know if you think there's some decent solution - paid or otherwise.

many thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom taxonomies and attach them with woo-commerce products. (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)

you can use the following plugin to create custom taxonomies if you are not familiar with coding:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

later use plugin like this to import taxonomy terms
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulkpress/